# Compare two JSONB arrays?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

#### requirement

filter all the users who know either of the languages [1,2,3,4,5]

// each number denote an enum of all the languages

#### dummy data

```
id  uid expertise(jsonb)                        languages(jsonb)
29  18  "[{""role"": 1, ""experience"": 2}]"    "[1, 2]"
3   13  "[{""role"": 1, ""experience"": 2}]"    "[1, 2]"
37  19  "[{""role"": 1, ""experience"": 2}]"    "[1, 2]"
```

These are the queries I wrote, but they are **not** returning anything `[]`

##### first query

```sql
select * from profiles where 
languages::jsonb ?| translate('[1,2,3,4,5]'::jsonb::text, '[]', '{}')::text[]
```

##### second query

```sql
select * from profiles
where languages::jsonb ?| array['1','2','3','4', '5']
```

I am coming from the world of mongo, please could someone explain?

Comment: This would be quite easy with a native array `languages && array[1,2,3,4,5]`. The `?|` operator doesn't work because it only works with strings, not with numbers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you mean alter table and change the language column type from `jsonb` -> `integer[]` ?

Comment: The best solution is to start off with a properly normalized model. That's what relational database are designed for and good at.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Okay, understood. Just one clarification, when you say "native array", you mean `integer[]` type column right?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to normalize your data model, this is what relational database are good at. And even though Postgres has pretty good support for JSON, it doesn't make it a "document database" as MongoDB. The `profiles` table should have a many-to-many relationship to a `language` table. That also allows you to have proper foreign key constraints to make sure that only languages (or their IDs) are referenced that actually exist.

Anyhow, I think the easiest way to do what you want, is an EXISTS condition:

```
select *
from profiles
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements_text(languages) as l(lang)
              where l.lang::int in (1,2,3,4,5));
```

Alternatively (if you do want to stick with a de-normalized model) it might be more efficient to define `languages` as `int[]`, not as `jsonb`. In that case, you can use the [overlaps operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) `&&`for arrays:

```
select *
from profiles
where languages && array[1,2,3,4,5];
```